# HTML5 Web Notification: Icon Image not shown if more Notifications will be created in short time

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-notifications

I am using Web Notifications. Now it could happen, that 2 notifications will be generated shortly after another. In Chrome (newst version), sometimes the icon won't be shown.

This happens ONLY if I use an internal image...

```
//this is a test icon
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    new Notification("Test",{
        icon:"https://someInternal.png",
        body:"TEST"
    });
}
```

Comment: What do mean by “internal image”?

Comment: by this, I mean an image which is not located external, but at the local server